# Show .shp file on Mapview(ArcGIS Android SDK 2.0.0)

Tags: android, arcgis, shapefile, offlineapps

I'm using ArcGIS Android SDK for first time. I woked on some sample project, able to get World map using this..

```
map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
map.addLayer(new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer("http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/ESRI_StreetMap_World_2D/MapServer"));
```

But my problem is i have some *.shp(shapefile) file want to show this on mapview how can i do that help me...

Thanks in Advance...!

Answer (score 1):

There is a sample in arcgis wpf samples.  [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/runtime-wpf/samples/index.html#/Add_Shapefiles_and_Rasters/02q20000004z000000/).  It takes in a shape file and projects that on top on a map server. Pretty sure it can easily be converted into Java as the sample is in C#